# Issue with Scaffolding Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, security, crud, myeclipse

i am using myEclipse to generate a CRUD spring web app , i want also add Spring Security using **Scaffolding Spring Security** from **Spring Tools**.
The web app is well generated and working fine , but i have an issue for the security part : the welcome page generated after succeful login doesn't contain the logout button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" >
    <intercept-url pattern='/pages/login.jsp' />
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" />
    <form-login login-page="/pages/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/pages/login.jsp?login_error=true"  /> 
    <logout logout-success-url="/pages/logout-redirect.jsp" invalidate-session="true" />
    <remember-me key="JPORMKey" user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" >
<authentication-provider user-service-ref='userDetailsService' >
    <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="springSecurityDataSource" />
    <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT username,password,enabled FROM Users WHERE username = ?" />
    <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT u.username, a.authorityname FROM Users u JOIN Users_Authorities ua on u.id = ua.user_id JOIN Authorities a on ua.authorities_id = a.id WHERE u.username = ?" />
</beans:bean>   

<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<!-- Apply security for all beans where security was set -->
<!-- ******************************************************************** -->
<global-method-security >
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* package.service.NewsService.*(..))" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED"/>
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* package.dao.NewsDAO.*(..))" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED"/>
</global-method-security>
```

any help guys ?

Comment: Could you mention the release of MyEclipse and the options you're choosing when creating the project and scaffolding the application? Also, after login, do you see any button in place of the Logout button?

Comment: i am using MyEclipse 2017 CI 10 , i choose DataBase as Security Type with md5 Password encoding , i Uncheck the option "secured" for AuthoritiesDAO and UsersDAO , for URL Pattern i put /* (i want secure the whole App) , i let the configuration view as default.
after a succefull login i get the login button still in my page , but no welcome page and no logout

Comment: Thanks for the details. I can see the same issue. I'm afraid there is no workaround other than checking the generated code yourself and fixing it manually. However, I've raised a problem report for the MyEclipse developers to investigate. Sorry about that!

Comment: thank you for help , can you provide me the link about the issue so i can track it ?

Comment: Sorry, Anass, we don't have a publicly visible tracking mechanism for issue with most features. Also, Spring issues don't get much focus currently, as we don't have many users calling for Spring feature updates. Consequently, I can't promise when, or even if, the problem will be addressed.